# Check Model in JQuery

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a property on my model called `CanExport`. My view inherits this model like so:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Chatham.Web.Models.Indications.ModelBase>" %>
```

How do I in javascript, check if that property is `true` or `false`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh I'm so mad at myself. I put in code to do this and thought it didn't work which was why I asked the question, but I realized that I didn't build. Sorry!

Here's the code if anyone is interested:

```
var showexport = "<%= Model.CanExportHistory%>"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getAttribute)

```
object.getAttribute('CanExport');
```

Comment: I can do that on the model though?

Comment: you asked about js. and i gave you a js answer. i dont really know asp.net

Comment: Oh, I was specifically asking about javascript interacting with a model in asp.net mvc